# Visual Studio Moving a Content File on Publish

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, installation, publishing

I'm developing a Web application that uses a couple XML files to store data.  I have their Build Action set to Content, and on install the files are copied successfully to the Applications Virtual Directory:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ApplicationName\
```

The problem I'm having is that writing to these XML files (in order to save settings and things like that) causes a lot of write permissions issues.  Therefore to get around it, I'm trying to copy these files from the virtual directory they're installed to to a new directory under the C drive, using the following PostBuildEvent in the Web Deployment Project:

```
xcopy "$(TargetDir)*.xml" "C:\CompanyName\ApplicationName\" /y
```

However, this does nothing.  I'm not sure if this is because PostBuildEvents in the installer are not actually fired on install, but only on building the installer, or if TargetDir represents the bin directory:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ApplicationName\bin\
```

instead of the root application virtual directory:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ApplicationName\
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Has anyone dealt with this sort of thing before? I'm really stumped on this one.

**Update:**
I included a PostBuildEvent that should give full permissions to all users:

```
icacls "$(TargetDir)" /grant Users:F
```

But it doesn't seem to have resolved the problem.

I'm also unsure where exactly $(TargetDir) if pointing to, if it would be ..\ApplicationName\ or ..\ApplicationName\bin\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is give full permissions to the user under whose context the Web Application Pool runs.

You can find this user by starting IIS manager and look at the **Application Pools** and **Identity** column

Something like

```
cacls C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ApplicationName /G Users:F
```

will give all permissions to this subdirectory to all users on the computer, If you are running under `ApplicationPoolIndentity` refer [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2009/02/13/goodbye-network-service.aspx)

Comment: An absolute file path isn't ideal, because the installer will refuse to compile if the virtual directory doesn't exist, which it doesn't until install.  Is there any way to access it in a relative fashion, such as withh $(TargetDir)?

Comment: I decided to use icacls instead of cacls, because Visual Studio gleefully informed me the cacls is deprecated and I shouldn't use it.  Turns out the user I'm interested in is ApplicationPoolIdentity apparently, but when running the command `icacls c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ApplicationName /grant ApplicationPoolIdentity:F` I get an error saying `No mapping between account names and security IDs was done`.

Comment: I ended up solving it in a different way, but I'll mark your answer as accepted regardless, because the information was useful.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's a much easier way to do what I was trying to do.

Instead of using PostBuildEvents to create a new directory structure and move files there, I added the new directory structure into

```
InstallerProject > View > File System
```

after which I located the ***Content Files from SomeProject*** entry in my installer project, and changed the ***Folder*** value to the newly specified directory structure, in this case

```
C:\CompanyName\ApplicationName\
```

This seems to work fine, I'm now able to access these files freely as I originally intended.